# How to fill the column values in excel?

Tags: excel

Its quite basic question, i dont use normally excel and thats why i am struggling. I have labeling data in excel like the picture attached.

[image]

Is there any way to fill the vlaues in blank spaces like this:

[image]

There are many thousands of rows and i cant fill manually. Any help?

Comment: drag down the cell. A double clic should work.

Comment: Yes but then i have to do for all the values manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this way:

1. Goto special(ctrl+G) -> select blankcell
2. Use [value code] header column in your image then input the formula as gif
3. Ctrl + enter -> Copy -> paste as value

[image]

Comment: Thanks seems what i am looking for. Can you also write the formula here?

Comment: Here is my formula: `=IF($D2<>"",A1,"")` , `D2 is the address of the cell [Value code] = 2`,  `A1 is the cell address [Vanable code] = "status"` and don't forget the $ in the formula.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Fill]

The easiest solution will be to double click on the highlighted.

Comment: If i double click then it stops until the next value. For example if i click on "Status" then it will stop on "Country" and then i have to double click again "Country". There are about 25000 variable and i can't double click for all.

Comment: In this situation you will need to delete the blanks. How to do it? 

1. Highlight the column
2. Press F5, click Special and select blanks
3. Right click on the highlighted column and click Delete and select Entire Row

Comment: I did but nothing happened. Its same as last t

Comment: Can you share a screen shot? Are you sure all the blanks have been deleted?

Answer (score 1):

If your original data is like first image: just double click on right spot marked

[image]

you can use a helper column, and drag the formula to END of data. The formula I've used is `=IF(B5<>"";B5;IF(C5<>"";A4;""))`

This is what I got after applying formula. Just paste values after that, and delete original column.

[image]

Comment: If i double click then it stops until the next value. For example if i click on "Status" then it will stop on "Country" and then i have to double click again "Country". There are about 25000 variable and i can't double click for all.

Comment: Oh, you need a formula or VBA, now I understand. What have you tried?

Comment: I just tried so far this double click... i never used vba or in excel